# How to rotate object after event click listener in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to create an application where a user can click an object then can rotate it. I am using three js to create this application. Currently I'm stuck because I have an object and I used a callback function to do stuff when an object is clicked.

I'm using the same idea as shown in the following link for finding the clicked item:
[Clickable three Js Objects / Convex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575800/clickable-three-js-objects-convex-items)

The problem is getting the object to rotate after it is clicked. I also have multiple objects, so each object has it's own callback function.

I have also found an example which I shows the rotation of a cube, but I haven't found any where an object is clicked and then some is done to it. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Check out [TransformControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js) and the related [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_transform.html)